# Difference between Dialogflow V1 API (Api.ai) and Dialogflow V2 API (Api.ai)?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Difference between  Dialogflow V1 API (Api.ai) and Dialogflow V2 API (Api.ai) ?

Answer (score 2):

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide

If you were using V1 for fulfillment or the API, the concepts are nearly all the same. But many names (and fields in the JSON) have changed.

V2 adds new ways to use the API, including directly by voice, and an Enterprise level version of the product.

Comment: Thank you for responding me, I got another good article as well. https://miningbusinessdata.com/dialogflow-api-v2-versus-v1/